# Cannot expire cookie from a controller in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, api, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-2.0

I am building an API in CakePHP. I have a function that as part of its execution first destroys the cookies associated with the session. I am using the following code to do this.

```
public function new_thing () {

    // I first call another controller to use functions from that controller
    App::import('Controller', 'Person');    
    $PersonsController = new PersonsController;

    // This function call is the problem
    // This does not throw any errors but does not destroy the cookie as requested
    $PersonsController->_kill_auth_cookie()

}


// This is from the Person controller, these are the functions used in the API

// This is the function that sets the cookies
public function _set_auth_cookie( $email ) {
    setcookie(Configure::read('auth_cookie_name'), $email);
}

// this is the function that does not properly destroy the cookie from the API
// interestingly, it does work when called from in this controller
public function _kill_auth_cookie() {
    setcookie(Configure::read('auth_cookie_name'), 'xxx', time()-7200);
}
```

I cannot get the API to properly expire the cookie that is created earlier in the session, I am not sure why. Additionally—what is maddening—is that the logs are empty and no error is being thrown of any kind, so I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Good lord, that’s some horrendous code. @burzum has done a good job of summing up why.

Answer (score 6):

There is so much wrong in this code and concept…

- **DON'T** instantiate controllers anywhere. It is plain wrong, broken by design and violates the MVC pattern. Only *one* controller should be dispatched by the framework itself based on the request; you don’t instantiate them manually.
- An API using cookies? Well, not impossible but definitely not nice to work with. It’s possible but I’ve *never* seen one in the wild. I feel sorry for the person who has to implement it. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141019/should-cookies-be-used-in-a-restful-api).
- Why are you not using the [CookieComponent](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CookieComponent.html)? It has a built-in [destroy()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CookieComponent.html#_destroy) method to remove a cookie.
- If you have an “auth” cookie, why are you not using CakePHP’s built-in Auth system? It will deal with all of that.
- Use `App::uses()` not `App::import()` here
- By convention, only protected functions should be prefixed with `_`

The first point is very likely the reason why cookie and sessions are messed up because the second controller instance initiates components again, and by this cookie and session maybe a second time as well. However, this can lead to “interesting” side effects.

> I first call another controller to use functions from that controller

This is the evidence that your architecture is broken by design. The code that needs to be executed somewhere else; should be in a model method in this case. Or at least a component if there are controller-related things to be shared between different controllers.